# how to remove Distinct on sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have query which takes long time to execute

```
SELECT 
    cft.ID, cft.Name AS 'CauseArea' , COUNT(DISTINCT e.ID) AS 'Donors',
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.DonationType = 1 THEN d.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'DonationsForAvarage' ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d.DonationType = 1 THEN d.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'EmployeeDonations' ,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.DonationType = 2 THEN d.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'MatchedDonations' ,
   SUM(CASE WHEN d.DonationType = 1 OR d.DonationType = 2 THEN d.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'TotalDonations'
FROM 
    dbo.Donation d
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Employee e ON e.ID = d.Employee
INNER JOIN 
    CharityProjectDetails cpd ON d.CharityProjectDetails = cpd.ID
INNER JOIN 
    CharityDetails cd ON cpd.CharityDetails = cd.ID
INNER JOIN 
    CauseFocusType cft ON cd.CauseFocusType = cft.ID
GROUP BY 
    cft.ID, cft.Name
```

So I have noted `DISTINCT` is the eater. I want to get rid of `DISTINCT` - how can I do that ?

Comment: Do you really need `dbo.Employee` in your query? Try removing it and use `COUNT(DISTINCT d.Employee) AS 'Donors'` to see if it makes difference

Comment: @cha yeah it not needed but some donations has without employee i want to get rid of those

Answer (score 1):

I have done it using subquery for Donation Table. Please check this if this is of any help to you.

```
        SELECT cft.ID
,cft.NAME AS 'CauseArea'
,d.cnt AS 'Donors'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'DonationsForAvarage'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'EmployeeDonations'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 2
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'MatchedDonations'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            OR d.DonationType = 2
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'TotalDonations'
FROM (SELECT  Employee
             ,DonationType
             ,CharityProjectDetails
             ,Amount
             ,COUNT(Employee) as cnt 
      FROM dbo.Donation
      GROUP BY Employee
             ,DonationType
             ,CharityProjectDetails
             ,Amount) d
INNER JOIN CharityProjectDetails cpd ON d.CharityProjectDetails = cpd.ID
INNER JOIN CharityDetails cd ON cpd.CharityDetails = cd.ID
INNER JOIN CauseFocusType cft ON cd.CauseFocusType = cft.ID
GROUP BY cft.ID
,cft.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the INNER JOIN on dbo.Employee is not required as you already have the data in dbo.Donation. Try this:

```
SELECT cft.ID
,cft.NAME AS 'CauseArea'
,COUNT(DISTINCT d.Employee) AS 'Donors'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'DonationsForAvarage'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'EmployeeDonations'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 2
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'MatchedDonations'
,SUM(CASE 
        WHEN d.DonationType = 1
            OR d.DonationType = 2
            THEN d.Amount
        ELSE 0
        END) AS 'TotalDonations'
FROM dbo.Donation d
INNER JOIN CharityProjectDetails cpd ON d.CharityProjectDetails = cpd.ID
INNER JOIN CharityDetails cd ON cpd.CharityDetails = cd.ID
INNER JOIN CauseFocusType cft ON cd.CauseFocusType = cft.ID
GROUP BY cft.ID
,cft.NAME
```

Comment: yeah i agreed employee doesn't need but the problem with query was `DISTINCT` keyword this query also takes long to execute.

Comment: OK, without being able to group by the employee column it's going to be difficult to avoid using a DISTINCT call. In the query plan, are all Indexes being selected properly? It may be better to look at other Performance issues before distinct if you can't easily avoid it.